# submit form from link outside form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I cannot figure out why this is not working.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Simply trying to submit my form with an outside link.

HTML:

```
<li><a href="#" id="paymentLink">Payment</a></li>
```

Note: that link is right above the form.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#paymentLink").click(function () {
            console.log("clicked!");
            $("#deliveryForm").submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note: "clicked!" does show in my console when clicking the link.

Comment: Is the form being selected? Try `console.log($("#deliveryForm").length);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please use this way.

```
<a href="#!" onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('deliveryForm').submit();">Payment</a>

<form id="deliveryForm" action="action.php" method="POST">
   <!-- Your Form Content Here -->

</form>
```

I think this way will work for you, this is very simple and shorter way.

Thank You :)

Comment: it is best to avoid inline click handlers when using jQuery

Comment: OK, that is weird.  I was going to ask what the ! was for.  And then I realized it did not work until I added in that !.  Weird, but it works!

Comment: What is the `#!` for? I cannot find a reference for it.

Comment: `#!` works like javascript void, which one used in Google materializecss, can you please check this link: http://materializecss.com/badges.html

Comment: Unfortunately that link does not explain it either. I would want to know the browser compatibility before using it :(

Comment: I found the the exact answer what you are looking for. It is actually used for make seo friendly html. When using # for dynamic content change the # to #! and then on the server $_REQUEST["_escaped_fragment_"] is what googlebot uses instead of #!  - also can you please this link :) http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-technical-details-should-a-programmer-of-a-web-application-consider-before/46760#46760